# Proving Principle Binormal of Arc Length Parametrized Curve is Contained in Hemisphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be naturally parametrized with $$ \int_a^b|\tau(s)|ds<2\pi. $$
Then, $B(s)$, the principle binormal, lies in a hemisphere of the unit sphere for all $s\in[a,b]$.

I'm meant to use Crofton's formula for this, but I have no idea how it is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Crofton. This is just a classic fact (from spherical geometry) that any curve of length $\le 2\pi$ in the unit sphere is contained in a closed hemisphere. It usually appears in the proof of Fenchel's Theorem.

See, for example, the last paragraph of the proof on pp. 25-26 in [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) or the lemma on pp. 113-114 of Chern's "Curves and Surfaces in Euclidean Space" in *Global Differential Geometry*, MAA Studies in Mathematics, volume 27.